# .net 4.0 markup-extensions WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, markup-extensions

I am back with another irritating problem. The problem is in .net 4.0 framework the TargetProperty type casting seems to have some problem and that's reported in msdn forums also. I've put up the code which i use here. Can someone suggest me a solution?

The MSDN link which speaks of this problem is pasted below:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/931d7bff-90b6-4a70-bb0b-3a097e1301a1

```
 var targetHelper = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
            targetProperty = targetHelper.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
            return ProvideValueInternal();
```

private object ProvideValueInternal()
        {
            object value = null;
            if (targetProperty != null)
            {
                IFontManager fontManager = DisplayResourceManager.Instance.FontManager;
                value = fontManager.GetFont(Key);
            }

`if (Converter != null)
        {
            value = Converter.Convert(value, targetProperty.PropertyType, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        return value;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if people chose not to answer this question thinking it was silly or because they didn't know the answer to the question. But anyways, i'll give the solution i found out. In .net 4.0 the targetHelper.TargetProperty doesn't return the proper expected type and instead i'd to find it out from the the target object as shown below

```
        if (targetHelper != null)
        {
            if (targetHelper.TargetObject is Setter)
            {
                targetProperty = (targetHelper.TargetObject as Setter).Property;
            }
        }
        if (targetProperty == null)
        {
            targetProperty = targetHelper.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
        }
```

Comment: I suspect people didn't answer because you didn't fully describe the problem in the question - you just linked it elsewhere.